# pip install flask-scaffold but having trouble downloading psycopg2-2.6

Tags: python

I have problems when I try `pip install flask-scaffold`
installing flask-scaffold. But having trouble downloading psycopg2-2.6, and I am using a virtualenv. Any help is welcome, thanks.

```
   Collecting psycopg2==2.6
      Using cached psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz (367 kB)
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'd:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\86131\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kwovtp
    7e\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\86131\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kwovtp7e\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'
    "'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg
    -base 'C:\Users\86131\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8deozwr4'
             cwd: C:\Users\86131\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kwovtp7e\psycopg2\
        Complete output (14 lines):
        running egg_info
        creating C:\Users\86131\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8deozwr4\psycopg2.egg-info
        writing C:\Users\86131\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8deozwr4\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to C:\Users\86131\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8deozwr4\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to C:\Users\86131\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8deozwr4\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
        writing manifest file 'C:\Users\86131\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8deozwr4\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        Error: pg_config executable not found.
        
        Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
        or specify the full executable path with the option:
        
            python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
        
        or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

pg_config is in postgresql-devel (libpq-dev in Debian/Ubuntu, libpq-devel on Centos/Fedora/Cygwin/Babun.)

try this:

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev

or

try to install brew install postgresql